# Angular 2, get edited data from HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Our angular 2 application  has a html table, that displays data from the database. Now we need to make few items editable in the table. I have made the needed items editable and added the button update, when clicked on the update button I need to get the edited value of the row along with the id of the row.

Please help me how to achieve it. Given below is my code.

```
        <tr  *ngFor="let row of tableData;">
        <td >{{ row.id}}</td>                   
        <td contenteditable="true">{{ row.editableData1 }}</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">{{ row.editableData2}}</td>
        <td style="color: black;">{{ row.user }}</td>
        <td class="link">
        <button  (click)="updatetoDB()" type="button">&nbsp;&nbsp;Update&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

So When user clicks on the Update Button, I need to get the edited data and the id of the row. Thank you in Advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#data1 method maybe not work because td element does not have value attribute.

Can you try to add an input element into your td like this :

```
<tr  *ngFor="let row of tableData;">
    <td >{{ row.id}}</td>                   
    <td contenteditable="true"><input type="text" [value]="row.editableData1" #data1/></td>
    <td contenteditable="true"><input type="text" [value]="row.editableData2" #data2/></td>
    <td style="color: black;">{{ row.user }}</td>
    <td class="link">
    <button  (click)="updatetoDB(data1, data2, row.id)" type="button">Update</button>
        </td>
</tr>
```

I think it should be working, but you habe to include an input element into your td.
It's annoying ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi,

The best solution is to use reactive form.

But i think you can name the edited data and pass it to your fonction updateToDB like this :

```
<tr  *ngFor="let row of tableData;">
        <td >{{ row.id}}</td>                   
        <td contenteditable="true" #data1>{{ row.editableData1 }}</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" #data2>{{ row.editableData2}}</td>
        <td style="color: black;">{{ row.user }}</td>
        <td class="link">
        <button  (click)="updatetoDB(data1, data2, row.id)" type="button">&nbsp;&nbsp;Update&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Log the content of data1 ans data2 variables, i think tour data should be in data1.value ans data2.value.

Hope that help you.

Comment: You can simply pass the row object to the function instead of 3 parameters. `updatetoDB(row)`

Comment: I'm not sure but i don't see data binding. The row datas maybe not updated when the function updatetoDB is called (function name should be updateToDb to better readability ;) ) .

Comment: you are right.my mistake.you need to use #data.and pass it like as you mentioned in your answer.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, Thanks for your suggestion, but when I followed your code, I am getting values of data1 and data2 as undefined.

Comment: Hi, i think it's because td element is not an input and does not contain any value attributes. See my new answer below.